# Populating Nested Array from Text File

Tags: javascript, node.js

Been trying to see if there might be an easier way for me to manage a dataset by putting it all into a text file rather than having it in the JS itself (the text file will be several hundred lines long by the end), but I can't seem to get the array to populate the way that I need it to.

In the end, I need an array that'll look like this:

```
var names = [
  {
    "name": "john",
    "tag": ["tall","blue eyes","ginger","fast"],
  },
   {
    "name": "morgan",
    "tag": ["stout","blue eyes","dark"],
  },
   {
    "name": "ryan",
    "tag": ["average","brown eyes","fast","strong","perceptive"]
  }
]
```

Populated with all the names and tags from the text file formatted like this (or something like this, if there's a formatting that'll work better):

```
john: tall ,blue eyes, ginger, fast
morgan: stout, blue eyes, dark
ryan: average, brown eyes, fast, strong, perceptive
```

Here's where I've gotten myself thus far, searching around here and elsewhere. Mostly struggling with the array of tags. Currently it's spitting it out as a string, but I'm not really sure how to break it down.

```
const { readFile, promises: fsPromises } = require('fs');

readFile('NAMES.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  var name = data.split(/\r?\n/), result = [], anotherarray = [];

  name.forEach((pair) => {
    if (pair !== '') {
      let splitpair = pair.split(': ');
      let key = splitpair[0].charAt(0).toLowerCase() + splitpair[0].slice(1);
      result[key] = splitpair[1];
    }
  });
  
  for (var i in result) anotherarray.push({ "name": i, "tag": result[i] });

  console.log(anotherarray);
});
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered storing the data in a JSON file and using `fs.readFile` combined with the built in `JSON.parse` function to parse it into an object?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/readline.html) node module to read the file line by line and process it.

I think the most simple way to process is in two steeps:

1. Split by name and tags by `:`
2. Split the tags by `,` and trim the spaces [recommend trim by split by `,`  so you can handle cases with multiple spaces]

**NOTE:** I added lowercase too because your example.

Example:

```js
const readline = require("readline");
const fs = require("fs");

// Create the interface to read the file line by line
const file = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('text.txt'),
});

// answer
const names = [];

// Process file line by line
file.addListener("line", (line) => {
    // Split name and tags
    const [name, tags] = line.split(":");

    // Insert the name with parsed tags
    names.push({
        name,
        tag: tags.split(",").map((e) => e.trim(). toLowerCase()),
    })
});

// Log answer
file.addListener("close", () => {
    console.log(names);
});
```

the output:

```
[
  { name: 'john', tag: [ 'tall', 'blue eyes', 'ginger', 'fast' ] },
  { name: 'morgan', tag: [ 'stout', 'blue eyes', 'dark' ] },
  {
    name: 'ryan',
    tag: [ 'average', 'brown eyes', 'fast', 'strong', 'perceptive' ]
  }
]
```